# Is it possible to block access to Safari's extensions?

Tags: safari, plugins

I'd like my son to have access to Safari but not to the extensions, as these provide content blockers to innapropriate material. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey can you please include the platform? iOS, Mac? [Edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/362623/edit)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blocking Safari Preferences you can turn on **Parental Controls** to restrict precisely time slots or what site content should be blocked.

- Open **System Preferences**
- Choose **Parental Control**
- Create a new user account with the restrictions you want for your son

[image: Parental Control]